# OverflowError: date value out of range when importing the excel sheet to data frame

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to import the excel sheet to data frame, everything is going fine until the pandas has been upgraded to 1.2.4, I get the OverflowError: date value out of range. I tried to uninstall pandas and install the former version(1.1.3), but nothing changes. What should I do?
Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
path='bugs.xlsx'
alldata=pd.read_excel(path,engine='openpyxl')
```

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjWsw.jpg)

[bugs.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTCWR.png)

Comment: Can you please post the bugs.xlsx file as well as the error code.
Wtih my 1.2.4 version of pandas it would do the job perfectly for me

Comment: Sure, I have post the details.